# How can I implement 'skip to content' links in Angular JS?

Tags: html, angularjs, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm trying to create a website that meets certain accessibility standards with tab clicks. I have a navigation menu on the left side of the screen and my users are requesting a "Skip to content" link so they don't have to constantly cycle through multiple links to get to where the content is.

However, I'm using AngularJS in my web app, and if I use the standard skip to content functionality (example: http://accessibility.oit.ncsu.edu/training/accessibility-handbook/skip-to-main-content.html), it won't work. I'm already using anchors (with #s) for the Angular code.

Is there any other way to implement this? I have a particular `div` tag that I would like the tab selection to go to. It should go to one of the elements inside the div.

Comment: you can add button/link and on click just focus any element u want - whats the problem?

Comment: The problem is that my "content" can be changed; since I'm using templates and `ui-router`. So I need it to goto the tab index of the element in the content

Comment: You can 'mark' first element in content on each page with special directive/id/class. Or you can select all tabable elements on page and skip navigate buttons. Thats not that cool way but at least something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [angular-scroll](https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll) to good effect before. It's lightweight (8.5kB), easy to use, and even takes care of scrolling animations for you. It also meets accessibility standards, as the Tab key can be used to navigate just like a normal anchor tag.

Implement like this:

**JS**

```
angular
.module('app', ['duScroll'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $document) {
  //Controller logic here
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#nav-one" du-smooth-scroll duration="1500">Navigation Link</a>

<!-- further down the page -->

<div id="nav-one">
  Content goes here.
</div>
```

Working CodePen for reference: http://codepen.io/Pangolin-/pen/dPQRZa

Comment: Problem is that I use angular `ui-router`. So when the user clicks on links, it doesn't refresh the whole page. and it has #'s to load content from other pages into the current main page, with a template. This won't work there as I need to go to the content.

Comment: It's not selecting the content. I need it to select. If the user navigates using the tab key and presses enter, they need to goto the content and see it selected.

Comment: It doesn't appear that [angular-scroll actually sets the `focus`](https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll/blob/master/angular-scroll.js) which is what is desired for keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked with [$anchor$croll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) and have some tips for you.

In your template:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="scrollTo('hello-scroll')">Go</a>
...
<div id="hello-scroll">Hello Scroll!</div>
```

In your controller:

```
angular
   .module('someModule', [])
   .controller('scrollCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $timeout, $anchorScroll) {

        /**
         * @name    scrollTo
         * @desc    Anchor scrolling within page using $anchorScroll
         * @param   {String}   hash - Element ID.
         * @return  void
         */
        $scope.scrollTo = function(hash) {
           $location.hash(hash);
           $timeout(function() {
              $anchorScroll();
            }, 100);
        }

    });
```

The reason I added the `$timeout` call is because when I tested it without it, the `$scrollTo` didn't seem to work. It seems that the call to `$location.hash(hash)` takes some small time to process, hence the 100 ms wait.